# SSD & Security & wipe Oh My

Tags: security, drive

So SSD's are memory based, and therefore solid state, meaning that they have no mechanical parts like a a regular spinning hard drive. How does this affect the need to wash empty disk space and will it unnecessarily increase wear on my drive?  It would seem that if it's memory, once you overwrite with ANYTHING the old data is gone. Sounds to good to be true though.

If you don't know what I mean, I'm talking about overwriting empty disk space to make sure any data there is unrecoverable. Tools for doing this are found in the wipe, and secure-delete packages. Wipe is facilitated through nautilus through the nautilus-wipe package.

Comment: This doesn't sound so much about Ubuntu as it does about SSD Technology...

Comment: Give it a few years and it will be about bloody everybody. ;-) It's about interacting with your hardware using Ubuntu. All of the commands are Ubuntu.

Comment: Oli, make this an answer so I can select it. It's awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [reading this Security.SE answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12506/12764) (and the links at the end).

It is true that overwriting a memory sector will wipe it without any of the ghosting old mechanical disks get, but the controllers for these disks have all sorts of life-prolonging features that obscure physical "sectors" away from the operating system.

For example, many modern disks reserve a portion (up to 20% of physical size) for wear levelling. Because this is all handled by the disk in the background, this prevents you from actually clearing everything. You *might* be able to get everything by doing a multi-pass write but it's hard to guarantee without doing a chip-by-chip analysis (which a determined attacker might).

As others have said before, if you want security you need to start with security:

- Buy drives that are hardware-encrypted.
- Use full disk encryption.

In either case, it's childplay to prevent the correct key being entered, rendering the data unusable without time-expensive cracking techniques. More than that, a wipe of an encrypted disk will knock out at least ~80% of the data (a mathematician will probably counter this), making it much harder to decrypt.

The only way to otherwise guarantee a secure wipe on an SSD is to destroy it.

Comment: I agree but I don't think encryption is enough with the NSA and other corporate and government goon squads poking about. Hardware encryption sounds awesome but we already know there have been sabotaged routers so why not hard drives? ...although I suppose if you have such a drive, you are just plain hosed.

Comment: Never forget that [a $5 iron wrench applied to the right body part](http://xkcd.com/538/) is far quicker at cracking passwords than the NSA's cluster. If you're doing stuff that requires that level of security, a single layer will never be enough.

Comment: Bringing a wrench to a gun fight might be a poor (read as "fatal") choice but your point is well taken.

Comment: Using the ATA SECURE ERASE feature ( see `hdparm` ) will erase everything, including the reserved erase blocks.  This also leaves all erase blocks in the erased state, unlike writing zeros to all logical blocks.

Comment: Any **ATA erase functions** are *geared* towards magnetic storage, and repeatedly *erasing* SSD (solid state) data does NOT actually remove any data previously stored. Instead in simply reduces the life of the device. *You need to use tools/features specifically designed for SSD security.*

Comment: @david6 OK that seems pretty doggone important since most new drives purchased are likely to be SSDs. Pardon my ignorance but can you provide clues/tips as to where to find these tools, assuming they exist?  Is there a package for them or would they be found as part of the hdparm stuff?  I assume hybrid drives would have BOTH sets of problems.

Comment: Best approach is to ONLY use the newer SSDs with 'SED' (*see my **answer** above/below.*) I don't think the tools themselves can do much, unless they are triggering SED functionality.

Comment: Well the problem I have with that pertains to some of my other comments. If you succeed in overwriting / removing / erasing / eliminating data, not even the NSA can get it because it's just plain no longer available. Encryption itself is useful but encryption can be broken or sabotaged and so can your legs, your family held hostage, etc. I suppose maybe what is needed is an emergency [break glass in case of security compromise] type deal that triggers a hammer and anvil type deal that makes your drive go CRUNCH.

Answer (score 0):

### Use 'SED' (*Self-Encrypting Drives*) technology:

> *The only way to otherwise guarantee a secure wipe on an SSD is to destroy it.*

While this is generally true, the latest generation of SSD have *Trusted Computing Group* '**Opal 2.0**' *transparent AES-256 encryption* of pages (storage elements), and discard this key when the page is no longer needed or has exceeded 'wear' (re-write) tolerance.

---

[Samsung > first 3D Vertical NAND SSD > SED technology](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/ssd850pro/overview.html)

> **Safeguard precious data without sacrificing performance**
>
> Protect your PC's hardware and personal data when you take your laptop on the road with the
>   850 PRO's SED technology. The drive includes an AES-256-bit hardware-based, full disk
>   encryption engine that secures your data without performance > degradation, often experienced
>   with software-based encryption.
>
> The 850 PRO's advanced security complies with the TCG™ Opal v2.0 standards, protecting PSID,
>   and is compatible with the Microsoft® eDrive IEEE® 1667 protocol. Plus, you can erase or
>   initialize data with the crypto erase service.

[ComputerWeekly > SED .. best-kept secret in hard drive encryption security](http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Self-encrypting-drives-SED-the-best-kept-secret-in-hard-drive-encryption-security)

> An SED is a self-encrypting hard drive with a circuit built into the disk drive controller chip that
>   encrypts all data to the magnetic media and decrypts all the data from the media automatically. All
>   SEDs encrypt all the time from the factory onwards, performing like any other hard drive, with the
>   encryption being completely transparent or invisible to the user.

**Note:** While HDDs can be erased with the right tools (and enough patience), SSDs will retain old data on *unused/discarded pages*. Unless you are using full-disk (or at least home-directory) encryption, this is a major security risk (for SSDs).

---

*This is what I use on my primary desktop PC(s) and notebook PC.*